# java assign next() to string or break into characters

Tags: java, variable-assignment, palindrome, stack

I am trying to create a program which will read a file and check whether the text is a palindrome or not. The code compiles, but doesnt really work.

The problem is I dont know how to break a complete token into characters or assign it to a string in order to use string's length to `push`(enqueue) each letter or digit into the `stack`(queue). Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
    StackReferenceBased stack = new StackReferenceBased();
    QueueReferenceBased queue = new QueueReferenceBased();
    Scanner s = null;
    String fileName=args[0]+".txt";
    int symbols = 0;
    int lettersAndDigits =0;
    int matches = 0;

    try{
      s = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
      while(s.hasNext()){
        String current = s.next();
        for(int i=0;i<current.length();i++){
          char temp = s.next().charAt(i);
          if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(temp)){
            stack.push(temp);
            queue.enqueue(temp);
            lettersAndDigits++;

          }
          else {
            symbols++;

          }
        }
      }
      System.out.println("There are: " + " "+ symbols + " " +"symbols and " + " "+lettersAndDigits + " "+ "digits/letters");


    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("Could not open the file:" + args[0]);
    } //catch (Exception e) {
      //System.out.println("ERROR copying file");
      finally {
      if(s != null){
        s.close();
      }
    }
    while (!stack.isEmpty()){
      if(!stack.pop().equals(queue.dequeue())){
          System.out.println("not pali");
          break;
        }
      else {
        ++matches;
      }
    }

    if(matches==lettersAndDigits){
      System.out.print("pali");
    }  
  }
```

Comment: Is this a homework? Otherwise, you are doing too much just to check if a string is a palindrome or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
char temp = s.next().charAt(i);
```

you need

```
char temp = current.charAt(i);
```

By calling `s.next()` you read the next token from the file and try to access the `i`th element of that token based on the first string's (`current`) length, which will lead to exceptions if the tokens read are shorter than the first stoken